# Sorting table rows by a column

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, geolocation

I have a list of cities with calculated distances using geolocation API in a table. I want to automatically sort the table rows by the distance column. 
I have tried several table sort plugin but all of them failed.

Any suggestion? here is my code: [jsfiddle.net/vLLsLLrb/](http://%20jsfiddle.net/vLLsLLrb/)

Here's how the table looks:

[image]

Comment: the link is not working

Comment: Is your code supposed to work? I would suggest first sort the data and then insert into the table. You don't need any plugin for this if you wanna keep lightweight and simple.

Comment: @OmidHezaveh link updated

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat Nouri yup it's work on my localhost..thank for you suggestion but I need to compare distance from each destination and if I have more destination, it would be large comparison to make..any idea?

Comment: Well if it's too large and you want to make it fast you can either use web workers or do it on server side or in the database.

Comment: The code didn't work, so I made some changes, http://jsfiddle.net/omidfi/vLLsLLrb/2/ now it works without sorting. So from here, can you add one of your efforts in sorting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it quickly, I used [sorttable.js](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/) by following these steps:

- include sorttable.js
- add class "sortable" to your table
- remove "km" from numbers (you can add them again later, using
  css:after)

Basically, mainly changing your table tag:

```
        <table id="nearest" class="table table-striped sortable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Destination</th>
                    <th>Distance to</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>London</th>
                    <td><span id='london'></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Newcastle</th>
                    <td><span id='newcastle'></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Cardiff</th>
                    <td><span id='cardiff'></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Cambridge</th>
                    <td><span id='cambridge'></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Reading</th>
                    <td><span id='reading'></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

That's it, now your distance column has a sorting triangle besides it! 
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/omidfi/vLLsLLrb/5/)'s the jsfiddle!

Comment: Thanks @OmidHezaveh, i have tried it using your solution, but when click the header, nothing happen..using different plugin also got same thing...

Comment: jsfiddle is blocking the sorttable.js file! Let me see where else I can host it!

Comment: Yeah..Thanks @OmidHezaveh

Comment: So please accept it as the answer, or edit your question IF it's not what you were looking for :)